# Gradle and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build

I am new to the whole Gradle thing and I find amazing already. I am experimenting with the tutorials they offer on their website on how to setup a project, build etc etc. My question is the following.

I have successfully set up my first project, build it and run it. After this Eclipse shows an error about not being able to find library imports (the ones resolved automatically by Gradle). How am I supposed to fix this?

Also are there any good addons for Eclipse that offer Gradle commands (I am currently building the project by running the command on Cygwin) as well as syntax highlighting for build file?